# Php cookie not deleting on logout

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I am making a web app, and when a user logs in, I am setting a cookie, but when they log out, the cookie won't delete.
My code to set the cookie:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    setcookie('name',$name);
}
```

My code to delete the cookie (I'm trying to set the expiration date to the past)

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
setcookie('name',"",time()-300);
}
```

I am fairly new to php, so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. Thanks in advance for any answers.

Edit: I am not using server sessions yet

Comment: dont use the cookie then store `name` in session... I hope your not using cookies for authentication persistence.

Comment: u need to destroy the session also session_destroy(); make sure to add session_start() before doing it.

Comment: are you sure `setcookie('name',"",time()-300);` statement is executed? and how do you know your cookie is not deleted? cookies are located in client side, so that it will be deleted after next request at the server side

Comment: What do you mean by "not using the cookie"?

Comment: the best thing would be $_SESSION = array();
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
}   session_destroy();

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you create a session (`$_SESSION`) for your user, then you have to destroy it when he logs out :

Plus, you may as well destroy the cookie (an empty string will answer `true` to php `isset()` function):

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
    unset($_COOKIE['name']);
    session_destroy();
}
```